# Is it possible to access music metadata from Win11 Apple Music App using APIs?

Tags: windows, audio-player, apple-music

Is there any way to get media data, e.g. music title, artist, album title, from Win11 Apple Music App? I have some Android development experience so may be the notifications could be get also in Windows?[Apple Music Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guGOV.png)

Or could I get the playing history form someplace without using Apple Music APIs (because it is not cheap)

I barely had any Windows develop experience, so it's hard for me to come up any idea, but if there is any way to achieve it, then I could know it's doable and learn some stuff about it.